# Count how many cells are null in a row using Linq and c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database for some movies. I want to count for each individual id how many cells are empty or null and display the count.

ex:

Id   Title  Price Genre

1  Last of Us 10  null

2  The others 8   Horror

3  X-Men     null null

I want to be able to display for id 3 that there are 2 missing values or for id 1 that there is 1 missing value

so far I have this code:

```
 Movie movieId = _context.Movies.Find(id);
 var movies = from m in _context.Movies where m.ID == id select m ;
 var model = new PartialModel();
 model.Count = movies.Count();
```

Unfortunately the code only displays how many movies with the specific id were selected. I tried x => x = null for count but it gives a syntax error.

I think i need a way to get the empty fields from movie but i don't know how to do that.

Thank you

Comment: Is ID defined as int or int?.  If you have null in an integer you need the question mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to add a property or method on the type and use reflection to count the number of public properties that have a `null` value. Do not do it inside of the `linq to sql` call, it does not belong there.

```
public class Movie {
  // existing properties


  // this should not be mapped back to the EF store
  public int NumberOfNullPropValues => typeof(Movie).GetProperties().Count(x => x.GetValue(this, null) == null);
}
```

*Note that this only works for reference types and `Nullable<T>`, it will not check for empty strings or for default values in the case the type is a struct (like 0 for `int`). Also if you want to check non public properties you need to pass binding flags to the `GetProperties` call*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reflection`

Like this (a method that returns how many null properties does an object have):

```
public int GetNullProperiesCount(object anyObject)
{
    var objType = anyObject.GetType();
    var nullCount = 0;

    foreach(var propInfo in objType.GetProperties())
    {
        if(propInfo.CanRead)
        {
           object val = propInfo.GetValue(anyValue, null);
           if(val == null) ++nullCount;
        }
    }
    return nullCount;
}
```

Then you can iterate through any collection and get how many null properties its items have.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection may be expensive in terms of CPU cycles. I'd use a DataSet to read and examine the data. It's easy to do and does not impose the overhead of Linq